How do I sign into iMessage on OS X 10.9 Mavericks?
I use Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks because it's my favorite version of OS X. I accidentally signed out of the Messages app (iMessage), and now I can't sign back in.
The first time I tried signing in, this message appeared:

An Apple ID verification code is required.
Type your password followed by the verification code shown on your other devices.

This also caused an Apple ID Verification Code to be sent to my iPhone.
However, on all subsequent attempts to sign in (with and without the verification code appended to the end of my password as instructed), I received this message:

Could not sign in to iMessage.
An error occurred during activation. Try again.

What can I do?

Solution

If you recently attempted to sign into iMessage, wait at least 30 minutes without attempting to sign in.

Open System Preferences → iCloud. If signed out, enter your Apple ID and password and click "Sign In". If already signed in, check the box next to "Keychain" and enter your password. In either case, ignore any error messages.

Wait until you receive an Apple ID Verification Code on one of your other devices. Do not use this code in System Preferences!

In the Messages app, sign into iMessage with (1) your Apple ID and (2) your password followed by the verification code you received. For example, if your password was "correcthorsebatterystaple" and your verification code was "123456", you'd enter "correcthorsebatterystaple123456" in the password field in Messages.


Messages should sign in successfully!
Explanation
I don't know what changed on Apple's servers, but for some reason, Macs running OS X 10.9 are limited to one iMessage sign-in attempt per approximately 30 minutes.
This conflicts with Apple's standard login process for older devices. Normally, the process looks like this:

Enter your Apple ID and password.
Receive a verification code.
Re-enter your Apple ID and your password followed by the verification code.

This is a really clever system! It allows older Apple software (from before the introduction of two-step verification) to continue signing in to modern accounts, without any client-side updates. However, it requires users to attempt to sign in twice in a row, and Messages can only attempt to sign in once every 30 minutes. This is longer than the time it takes verification codes to expire.
Luckily, System Preferences is not limited to one sign-in attempt per 30 minutes, and Apple doesn't seem to mind that we're using the code in a different app from where we requested it.
This answer is valid as of December 31, 2024 and I do not know what Apple's servers will decide to allow in the future.

This is a curious interaction indeed.

@Eric Thank you for the Keychain idea, super clever! Syncing keychain is broken on 10.9 so there's no chance someone will already have this enabled--right?

@Eric (Also, I'm assuming you've tested this actually works, as I have not as of this writing!)
